# hibernate - fetching from database for every page

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a scenario wherein I need to display on all jsp pages that the user will browse, the count of nametags associated with his account.  This count of nametags can be increased/decreased by user's action or by other user's as well.

What is the best way to implement this?  Currently,  I'm fetching from database for every method in my controller so I cam be sure that the data that will be shown is really update.  This is at the cost of performance though.  Any advise how can this be achieved efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please let us knw what you mean by users's action and nametags?

Comment: Store it in session, so that you need to load it only once per user for its session.

Comment: User's actions.  Like when he add a nametag using a form.  Other user can also add a nametag for other people.

Comment: @Jay , but other people can add nametag for other users as well.  If I store it in session, if other people update it, how will it be reflected automatically? For your advise, thanks!